# Can we change the dEFAULT_FD_BUFFER_SIZE value for our own?

Tags: haskell

I have looked at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-IO-FD.html. There it states:

```
-- We used to use System.Posix.Internals.dEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, which is
-- taken from the value of BUFSIZ on the current platform.  This value
-- varies too much though: it is 512 on Windows, 1024 on OS X and 8192
-- on Linux.  So let's just use a decent size on every platform:
dEFAULT_FD_BUFFER_SIZE :: Int
dEFAULT_FD_BUFFER_SIZE = 8096
```

Can we change the dEFAULT_FD_BUFFER_SIZE value for our own?

Comment: 8096 is a curious size. Is it a simple typo, or are 96 bytes of overhead expected (but not called out with a comment anywhere in that source file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in the source and compile GHC with the new size. That may have performance implications (it certainly will for extreme values), but otherwise you probably wouldn't notice.

Other than that, you can't change it.

A quick search in the source of [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) showed only one use site, the

```
instance BufferedIO FD where
  newBuffer _dev state = newByteBuffer dEFAULT_FD_BUFFER_SIZE state
  fillReadBuffer    fd buf = readBuf' fd buf
  fillReadBuffer0   fd buf = readBufNonBlocking fd buf
  flushWriteBuffer  fd buf = writeBuf' fd buf
  flushWriteBuffer0 fd buf = writeBufNonBlocking fd buf
```

so there's no place where you could plug in a different value after compilation.